# ClientException: Connection closed before full header was received

Tags: java, flutter, dart, http

I have a strange problem:

This code is working on physical device (Android 10) with java application (Android Studio)

```
final MediaType JSON
                    = MediaType.get("application/xml; charset=utf-8");

            OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().
                    writeTimeout(timeout, TimeUnit.SECONDS).
                    readTimeout(timeout, TimeUnit.SECONDS).
                    connectTimeout(timeout, TimeUnit.SECONDS).build();

            RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(xml, JSON);
            Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url("http://"+ ipMachine + "/service.cgi")
                    .post(body)
                    .build();

            Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
```

This one returns "ClientException: Connection closed before full header was received" in Flutter same device.

```
http.Response response = await http.post(
            Uri.http(ip, "service.cgi"),
            headers: {
              HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader: "application/xml; charset=utf-8",
            },
            body: xml);
```

The server is a fiscal printer (RCH).

Please, help me.

Thanks.

**UPDATE:**

if I use flutter_curl package in flutter it works:

```
Client client = Client(
          verbose: true,
          interceptors: [
            // HTTPCaching(),
          ],
        );
        await client.init();

        final res = await client.send(Request(
            method: "POST",
            url: "http://192.168.168.18/service.cgi",
            headers: {"user-agent": "myapp-v1.0/android9"},
            // body
            body: RequestBody.raw(utf8.encode(xml))
            // body: RequestBody.string("hello world"),
            // body: RequestBody.form({"age": "10", "hello": "world"}),
            // body: RequestBody.multipart([
            //    Multipart(name: "age", data: "24"),
            //    Multipart(name: "hello", data: "world"),
            //    Multipart.file(
            //      name: "fieldname",
            //      path: "/sdcard/todo.txt",
            //      filename: "filename.txt",
            //    ),
            //  ]),

            ));
        print("Status: ${res.statusCode}");
        print("HTTP: ${res.httpVersion}");
        res.headers.forEach((key, value) {
          print("$key: $value");
        });
        print(res.text());
```

It's ok but i need that this work also in windows and flutter_curl doesn't support it.